# Access session cookie in scrapy spiders

Tags: session, cookies, session-cookies, scrapy

I am trying to access the session cookie within a spider.  I first login to a social network using in a spider:

```
    def parse(self, response):

        return [FormRequest.from_response(response,
                formname='login_form',
                formdata={'email': '...', 'pass':'...'},
                callback=self.after_login)]
```

In `after_login`, I would like to access the session cookies, in order to pass them to another module (selenium here) to further process the page with an authentificated session.

I would like something like that:

```
     def after_login(self, response):

        # process response
        .....

        # access the cookies of that session to access another URL in the
        # same domain with the autehnticated session.
        # Something like:
        session_cookies = XXX.get_session_cookies()
        data = another_function(url,cookies)
```

Unfortunately, `response.cookies`  does not return the session cookies.

How can I get the session cookies ?  I was looking at the cookies middleware: *scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.cookies* and *scrapy.http.cookies* but there doesn't seem to be any straightforward way to access the session cookies.

**Some more details here bout my original question:**

Unfortunately, I used your idea but I dind't see the cookies, although I know for sure that they exists since the *scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.cookies* middleware does print out the cookies!  These are exactly the cookies that I want to grab.

So here is what I am doing:

The after_login(self,response) method receives the response variable after proper authentication, and then I access an URL with the session data:

```
  def after_login(self, response):

        # testing to see if I can get the session cookies
        cookieJar = response.meta.setdefault('cookie_jar', CookieJar())
        cookieJar.extract_cookies(response, response.request)
        cookies_test = cookieJar._cookies
        print "cookies - test:",cookies_test

        # URL access with authenticated session
        url = "http://site.org/?id=XXXX"     
        request = Request(url=url,callback=self.get_pict)   
        return [request]
```

As the output below shows, there are indeed cookies, but I fail to capture them with cookieJar:

```
cookies - test: {}
2012-01-02 22:44:39-0800 [myspider] DEBUG: Sending cookies to: <GET http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=529907453>
    Cookie: xxx=3..........; yyy=34.............; zzz=.................; uuu=44..........
```

So I would like to get a dictionary containing the keys xxx, yyy etc with the corresponding values.

Thanks :)

Comment: Do i understand correctly that you want to authenticate on facebook, but scrape data from a different domain being authenticated on facebook?

Answer (score 12):

A classic example is having a login server, which provides a new session id after a successful login. This new session id should be used with another request.

Here is the code picked up from source which seems to work for me.

```
print 'cookie from login', response.headers.getlist('Set-Cookie')[0].split(";")[0].split("=")[1]
```

Code:

```
def check_logged(self, response):
tmpCookie = response.headers.getlist('Set-Cookie')[0].split(";")[0].split("=")[1]
print 'cookie from login', response.headers.getlist('Set-Cookie')[0].split(";")[0].split("=")[1]
cookieHolder=dict(SESSION_ID=tmpCookie)

#print response.body
if "my name" in response.body:
    yield Request(url="<<new url for another server>>",   
        cookies=cookieHolder,
        callback=self."<<another function here>>")
else:
    print "login failed"
        return
```

Answer (score 7):

Maybe this is an overkill, but i don't know how are you going to use those cookies, so it might be useful (an excerpt from real code - adapt it to your case):

```
from scrapy.http.cookies import CookieJar

class MySpider(BaseSpider):

    def parse(self, response):

        cookieJar = response.meta.setdefault('cookie_jar', CookieJar())
        cookieJar.extract_cookies(response, response.request)
        request = Request(nextPageLink, callback = self.parse2,
                      meta = {'dont_merge_cookies': True, 'cookie_jar': cookieJar})
        cookieJar.add_cookie_header(request) # apply Set-Cookie ourselves
```

`CookieJar` has some useful methods.

If you still don't see the cookies - maybe they are not there?

---

**UPDATE**:

Looking at `CookiesMiddleware` code:

```
class CookiesMiddleware(object):
    def _debug_cookie(self, request, spider):
        if self.debug:
            cl = request.headers.getlist('Cookie')
            if cl:
                msg = "Sending cookies to: %s" % request + os.linesep
                msg += os.linesep.join("Cookie: %s" % c for c in cl)
                log.msg(msg, spider=spider, level=log.DEBUG)
```

So, try `request.headers.getlist('Cookie')`

Comment: Many thanks for your answer!  Unfortunately it still didn't work.  Howver, I know for sure there are cookies.  See post below for what I did.

Comment: Please see my edit to the original post to see my response! Many thanks :)

Comment: @mikolune, see the update. Also, learn to look into source code - that's why Python is good - you can look into source code, which is sometimes the best documentation.

Comment: Many thanks  warvariuc.  For my particular problem, I found a way around to not have to access the cookies (it had additional benefits as well).   But this seems to be the solution.  I will try anyway in a few days and let you know here how it went.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
response.request.headers.get('Cookie')
```

It seems to return all the cookies that where introduced by the middleware in the request, session's or otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2021 (Scrapy 2.5.1), this is still not particularly straightforward. But you can access downloader middlewares (like CookiesMiddleware) from within a spider via `self.crawler.engine.downloader`:

```py
def after_login(self, response):
    downloader_middlewares = self.crawler.engine.downloader.middleware.middlewares
    cookies_mw = next(iter(mw for mw in downloader_middlewares if isinstance(mw, CookiesMiddleware)))
    jar = cookies_mw.jars[response.meta.get('cookiejar')].jar

    cookies_list = [vars(cookie) for domain in jar._cookies.values() for path in domain.values() for cookie in path.values()]
    # or
    cookies_dict = {cookie.name: cookie.value for domain in jar._cookies.values() for path in domain.values() for cookie in path.values()}

    ...
```

Both output formats above can be passed to other requests using the `cookies` parameter.