# How to pass Scrapy login cookies to Selenium?

Tags: cookies, selenium, scrapy

I need Selenium for javascript work.

First I login using Scrapy `FormRequest` and then I need to open the `response.url` with Selenium.

The problem is that Selenium does not have the cookies so It opens the login page.

Does anyone know how can I pass the cookies from scrapy to selenium?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you haven't provided any code you've written so far, I'll just refer you.

In order to get cookies from Scrapy take a look at `scrapy.http.cookies.CookieJar` and `extract_cookie` method (see [Scrapy - how to manage cookies/sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981440/scrapy-how-to-manage-cookies-sessions)).

In order to set cookies for selenium driver, see [add_cookie](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.add_cookie) method.

Also see:

- [scrapy authentication login with cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11200926/scrapy-authentication-login-with-cookies)
- [Access session cookie in scrapy spiders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708346/access-session-cookie-in-scrapy-spiders)

Comment: Thanks, I found easy solution. I just login Selenium session.
This was so easy.
so I have both Scrapy and Selenium logged in